# Generate IIS application key programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, command-line

Using the IIS manager GUI, it is easy to use the 'Connections' tree view to navigate to an application, under ASP.Net open 'Machine Key', and then click 'Generate Keys' in order to generate a key for your application for the purpose of setting up a shared ASP.Net session across machines.

However, when I read the documentation for [Generate a Machine Key](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772287(v=ws.10).aspx), the only thing I get is the cryptic

> Use the following WMI classes, methods, or properties to perform this
>   procedure:
>
> MachineKeySection class. Keys are generated by setting
>   properties, so no method is needed.)

The incorrect punctuation does not boost my confidence and I'm not sure how to implement this advice regardless. How do I generate validation and decryption keys for my IIS application via the command line? I'm also willing to generate them via C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could use the [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) class to generate the required keys using PowerShell. It is the same class IIS manager itself uses to generate those keys.

I have learned from [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2009/05/13/iis-7-tip-10-you-can-generate-machine-keys-from-the-iis-manager.aspx) blog about the way IIS manager is using that class.

> With IIS 7 you no longer have to do this manually. The IIS 7.0 manager has a built in feature that you can use to generate these keys. It uses RNGCryptoServiceProvider internally to create a random key.

The post author is a Microsoft employee - I do not know him personally though.

[Here](http://poshcode.org/2275) is one example of using it with the PowerShell script approach.

Comment: I'm sure your aware it's customary in StackOverflow answers to include a summary of the contents of a link or the highlights that specifically answer the question. The goal of SE sites is to become a resource of knowledge, of answers, for years to come. With a link-only answer, the op must dig through another resource to locate an answer he/she might not be sure about. Most importantly, if your link were to ever break, your answer is useless for anyone who visits this page in the future.

Comment: This is a good answer that I will investigate. I'd really like to see it include an authoritative source stating IIS uses that class.

Comment: @Jeremy I am yet to figure out all the community rules - Thank you for your input. I agree the links could be broken - but the OP wanted a way to script the generation of keys. I felt the way IIS manager was doing it is but an interesting anecdote not the foundation of the whole answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ManagementClass class from System.Management to connect to WMI. Using this class you can manipulate WMI instances.
Please follow below mentioned steps:

1. Create new console application.
2. Add reference to System.Management assembly.
3. Add using statement as follows

   ```
   using System.Management
   ```
4. Use below code to connect to MachineKeySection class.

   ```
   string NamespacePath = "\\\\.\\ROOT\\WebAdministration";

   string ClassName = "MachineKeySection";

   ManagementClass oClass = new ManagementClass(NamespacePath + ":" + ClassName);

   foreach (ManagementObject oObject in oClass.GetInstances())
   {
       Console.WriteLine("ApplicationName : {0}", oObject["ApplicationName"]);
   }
   ```
5. You can use following screenshot to check available properties and methods.
   [WMI Explorer](https://wmie.codeplex.com/)

[image]

Comment: When I run this, `oClass.GetInstances()` crashes if I'm not an administrator. If I am, it returns an empty `ManagementObjectCollection`.